# ASP.NET MVC: Trying to test a helper method, but having problems with "resetting" my objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, dbcontext

I am trying to test a helper method using a Test Project in VS2012 Web Express using ASP.NET MVC. I don't want to use my regular database for testing, so I have added the following the App.Config to the Test Project:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UnitTest.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Setting up my Unittest looks something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething()
{
    MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase();

    //Initialize objects and save them in the (test) database

    db.SaveChanges();

    //Initializing the class that contains the method I want to test
    TestUserClass tuc= new TestUserClass();

    //Calling the method I want to test
    tuc.TestUserMethod (1, 1);

    //Check the database if everything is correct
}
```

This is working fine, I am using my test database and all the correct objects are created. However the problem comes when I initialize the class containg the method I want to test. Since the TestUserClass also uses the database it also initializes a Database like this

```
//In the class TestUserClass 
MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase();
```

The MyDatabase class looks something like this:

```
public class MyDatabase : DbContext
{
    public MyDatabase()
        : base("MyConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDatabase>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDatabase>());
    }

    public DbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
}
```

The problem occurs as soon as I initialize the class I want to test. Before that my db object contains all the right objects, but after I initialize my TestUserClass and therefore creates another MyDatabase object, the db object contains nothing (all the right sets are there, they are just empty).

I assume the problem is that I initialize the MyDatabase object again (obviously?). But I am not sure how to solve this problem. Is it a problem with my application design, my unittest or am I just missing some silly little piece of code that allows me to use the database without initializing it and therefore resetting the object?

Best regards and thank you in advance!

Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question (I don't know how it actually works, trial and error FTW). I added an overloaded contructor to TestUserClass:

```
public UserManagement()
{
   db = new RefusionsDatabase();
}

public UserManagement(RefusionsDatabase dbIn)
{
   db = dbIn;
}
```

AND moved the initialization of the TestUserClass to right after the MyDatabase Initialization (not sure why this is necessary, but it was).

```
MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase();
TestUserClass tuc= new TestUserClass(db);
```

And now it works.

Hope it helps somebody

Andreas

PS: If someone knows why this works, knows a better solution OR have a comment on the design I would be glad, because it is weird without an explanation.